# How to get row by row data from excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am new to c# and i have a simple project on c# in which i want to get some data from excel in c# and i want to save it in database, i have no idea about it, i found the following code and its working well but not giving me the data, here is code:

```
 var fileName = @"C:\Users\AhsanWindows8\Desktop\Book1.xlsx";
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
```

now this is how my excel file looks like

[image]

Can I get this data in a dictionary like key value pair, suppose English word on left side will be key and text on right side will be value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "$] ";
```

When dataset will be filled you can use this code to construct dictionary.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  dict.Add(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString());
}
```

If you are familiar with LINQ, you can try use this:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.ToDictionary(r => r[0].Tostring(), r => r[1].Tostring());
```

Comment: i still don't know how to convert that data into dictionary ( key , Value )